# anonymous function error

Tags: jquery, function

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the following?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav_menu .dropdown').css('display', 'block');
    $('ul.nav').toggleclass('dropmenu');
    $('.nav_menu > ul').dropmenu({
        effect: 'slide',
        speed: 250,
        timeout: 0,
        nbsp: false
    });
});​
```

Safari reports that the toggleclass is an anonymoous function, whatever that means!

thanks

Comment: What _exactly_ does the error say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing the camel case on `toggleClass`

```
//                v--- case C instead of c
$('ul.nav').toggleClass('dropmenu');
```

Answer (score 4):

**It's a typo: c --> C** 
it should be:

```
.toggleClass()
       ^-------------camelCase, big C
```